# Present Controller using iOS Safe Area Layout

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, safearealayoutguide

[image]

I am using iOS 11 safe area layout guidelines and set background color of status bar like this

```
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
     }
} 

UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .green
```

When presenting a controller with the red background it doesn't cover status bar as shown in the image but it works fine when not using safe area layout guidelines. Whats going wrong here?

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
vc.backgroundColor = .red
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: where do you run this line

Comment: this one UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .green ?

Comment: yes ..............

Comment: You can clear your UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .clear that will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Sh_Khan in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Comment: @iOSTeam that's fine but when I change the alpha of presented controller then status bar's color looks gray and navigation bar color of navigation controller is green means both are different. I want both colors same when I see through from presented controller. Hope you understand.